# Linux OS does not reset

Tags: xubuntu

I have noticed this in every linux OS I have tried. When I attempt to a reboot, it hangs and forces me to manually shut it off. I cant imagine that this is good for my netbook and was wondering if this can be changed. I have tried Mint 12 & 9, Ubuntu 11, and Xubuntu and they all do this.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find out why it is hanging you could remove the "quiet splash" flags from grub2. This should allow you to see where it jams.

Run

```
sudo nano -w /etc/default/grub
```

then change the line

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

to

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""

Then save, and

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now when you boot/shutdown the splash screen will be gone and you'll get lots of info as to whats going on.